# Unable to see shapefile on the device

Tags: android, gis, arcgis

I am trying to add london shapefile for buildings in my android app. However, I am unable to display it. Its showing nothing on the map. But the same shapefile is getting displayed properly online. So, there is nothing wrong with the shapefile.

I downloaded shapefile from
https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0kRhiw4fD7uQzU3MzBMRzFfSFk&export=download

My code:
layout.xml

```
<!-- MapView layout and initial basemap and extent. -->


<com.esri.android.map.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    mapoptions.ZoomLevel="5"
    mapoptions.center="18.0000, 79.5800" >
</com.esri.android.map.MapView>
```

MapActivity.java

```
    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.enableWrapAround(true);
    String mShapefilePath = "/london_buildings/TQTL_LON.shp";

    String mSdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer mTiledlayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(
            "http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/ESRI_Imagery_World_2D/MapServer");

    mMapView.addLayer(mTiledlayer);

    try {
        shpFileFeatTable = new ShapefileFeatureTable(mSdcard + mShapefilePath);
        mFlayer = new FeatureLayer(shpFileFeatTable);
        mFlayer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(new SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.CYAN, 2, STYLE.SQUARE)));

        mMapView.addLayer(mFlayer);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not found in SDCard, nothing to load", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Log.d("**ShapefileTest**", "File not found in SDCard, nothing to load");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not found in SDCard, nothing to load", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make two changes:

1. The [`MapView`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/MapView.html) will not re-project [`ShapefileFeatureTable`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geodatabase/ShapefileFeatureTable.html) on the fly. The shapefile has to be in the same spatial reference as the map. You start by adding a map service that is in the WGS 1984 spatial reference, which sets the `MapView`'s spatial reference to WGS 1984. But the shapefile is in British National Grid. You must either 1) use ArcMap to project* the shapefile to WGS 1984 and push the new shapefile to your device or 2) not add the map service layer to the map. `MapView` won't re-project a tiled service on the fly either, so you have to project the shapefile ahead of time if you want to display both of these layers together in Android.
2. You're giving your [`SimpleRenderer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/renderer/SimpleRenderer.html) a [`SimpleMarkerSymbol`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/symbol/SimpleMarkerSymbol.html). `SimpleMarkerSymbol` is only for points. For polygons, like the shapefile you shared, you must use a [`SimpleFillSymbol`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/symbol/SimpleFillSymbol.html) instead. So do something like this:

   ```
   SimpleFillSymbol symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(Color.CYAN, SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE.SOLID);
   symbol.setOutline(new SimpleLineSymbol(Color.LTGRAY, 1));
   ```

* Un-project, actually, since you're going from a projected coordinate system to a geographic coordinate system, but use the [Project](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm) tool to do it.